# Use macro codes in Delphi like C/C++

Tags: delphi, macros, pascal

I found this macro code in Delphi/Pascal syntax but i can't use it! Does Delphi support macro codes like C/C++ or this macro is for another language such as Lazarus ???

The macro :

```
{$ifdef Profile}
  {$define __TRACE__:= try }
  {$define __END__:= finally ShowMessage('Hello !'); end;}
{$else}
  {$define __TRACE__:= //}
  {$define __END__:=}
{$endif}
```

I'm trying to use like this :

```
    ...
   __TRACE__
     // Somethings
    __END__
    ...
```

I caught this compiler message :

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(37): E2003 Undeclared identifier: '__TRACE__'
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(38): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(39): E2003 Undeclared identifier: '__END__'
```

{Excuse me if my English is bad}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [Free Pascal macros](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progse5.html#x138-1390002.2). There's nothing at all like this available for the Delphi compiler. Some options:

- Use a logging framework (there are many good logging libraries available) to add trace debug facilities to the code. Frankly that would be a huge improvement on what is shown here.
- Expand the code manually. That is each time you see `__TRACE__` in the code, replace that with an inline `$IFDEF`. Not appealing at all.

Comment: Note that macros were mainly added to avoid endless {$ifdef mswindows} stdcall;{$else}cdecl;{$endif} sequences in headers. That is the only thing they are used for in FPC atm. There are no plans to expand.